# `lazy_dt` not support `dplyr/across`?

Tags: r, dplyr, across, dtplyr

The code show error message  as below

```
This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates.
```

It means `lazy_dt` not support `across` ? Thanks !

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dtplyr)
diamonds %>% lazy_dt() %>% group_by(color) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `dtplyr` does not support `where()`. See [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/447) closed issue on GH.

Instead one possible workaround would be to use a vector of the names of numeric columns with `all_of`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dtplyr)

num_cols <- names(diamonds)[
  sapply(diamonds, is.numeric)
]

diamonds %>%
  lazy_dt() %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(num_cols), ~ sum(.)))
#> Source: local data table [7 x 8]
#> Call:   `_DT1`[, .(carat = sum(carat), depth = sum(depth), table = sum(table), 
#>     price = sum(price), x = sum(x), y = sum(y), z = sum(z)), 
#>     keyby = .(color)]
#> 
#>   color carat   depth   table    price      x      y      z
#>   <ord> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 D     4457. 418005. 388916. 21476439 36701. 36728. 22648.
#> 2 E     6445. 604104. 563241. 30142944 53017. 53090. 32729.
#> 3 F     7028. 588690. 548031. 35542866 53578. 53621. 33058.
#> 4 G     8708. 697361. 646903. 45158240 64111. 64141. 39579.
#> 5 H     7572. 513493. 477628. 37257301 49686. 49698. 30691.
#> 6 I     5568. 335331. 312184  27608146 33740. 33740. 20850.
#> # ℹ 1 more row
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

or use `summarise_if` (however, be aware that `summarise_if` is superseded):

```
diamonds %>%
  lazy_dt() %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarise_if(~ is.numeric(.x), sum)
#> Source: local data table [7 x 8]
#> Call:   `_DT3`[, .(carat = sum(carat), depth = sum(depth), table = sum(table), 
#>     price = sum(price), x = sum(x), y = sum(y), z = sum(z)), 
#>     keyby = .(color)]
#> 
#>   color carat   depth   table    price      x      y      z
#>   <ord> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 D     4457. 418005. 388916. 21476439 36701. 36728. 22648.
#> 2 E     6445. 604104. 563241. 30142944 53017. 53090. 32729.
#> 3 F     7028. 588690. 548031. 35542866 53578. 53621. 33058.
#> 4 G     8708. 697361. 646903. 45158240 64111. 64141. 39579.
#> 5 H     7572. 513493. 477628. 37257301 49686. 49698. 30691.
#> 6 I     5568. 335331. 312184  27608146 33740. 33740. 20850.
#> # ℹ 1 more row
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to work on lazy data, "need" the ability to operate only on numeric columns, and cannot load the whole data, you can load one row, get the `where(.)`-like metadata you'll need, and use that in `all_of` as stefan suggested.

```r
data("diamonds", package="ggplot2")
library(dtplyr)
lazydia <- lazy_dt(diamonds)
sapply(lazydia, is.numeric) # does not work while lazy
#        parent          vars        groups        locals implicit_copy    needs_copy           env          name 
#         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE 
num_cols <- lazydia |>
  head(1) |>
  collect() |>
  sapply(is.numeric)
num_cols <- names(num_cols)[num_cols]
num_cols
# [1] "carat" "depth" "table" "price" "x"     "y"     "z"
```

With this, you can continue with @stefan's use of `across(all_of(num_cols), ..)`:

```r
lazydia |>
  group_by(color) |>
  summarise(across(all_of(num_cols), ~ sum(.))) |>
  collect()
# # A tibble: 7 × 8
#   color carat   depth   table    price      x      y      z
#   <ord> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 D     4457. 418005. 388916. 21476439 36701. 36728. 22648.
# 2 E     6445. 604104. 563241. 30142944 53017. 53090. 32729.
# 3 F     7028. 588690. 548031. 35542866 53578. 53621. 33058.
# 4 G     8708. 697361. 646903. 45158240 64111. 64141. 39579.
# 5 H     7572. 513493. 477628. 37257301 49686. 49698. 30691.
# 6 I     5568. 335331. 312184  27608146 33740. 33740. 20850.
# 7 J     3263. 173779. 162337. 14949281 18306. 18303. 11325.
```